# Where to locate FluentMigrator classes?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu, fluent-migrator

So I have web app that I'm planning to upload to Azure Websites, and I have my Project.Model.csproj using NH and my Project.Model.Migrations.csproj using FluentMigrator.

When trying to run the deployment using Kudu, I found that my Migrations.csproj was not getting compiled because it was not part of the references tree for web.csproj (which is the right thing to do I am guessing).

So immediately I tried to modify my deploy.cmd so it launches the msbuild for that Migrations.csproj. However, I found that it could lead to other problems especially with KuduSync since I'm compiling outside the "main flow" of the usual kudu logic.

My question is: is it right to have Model.csproj and Migrations.csproj?. It is logical based on maintenance and order, but it falls into these kind of problems.

If it's ok to separate, then how can I change the kudu script to work soundly on most cases?.

This is the script (shortened for brevity).

```
:: 2. Build to the temporary path
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_PATH%" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Code\web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"; ...
) ELSE (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_PATH%" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Code\web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /p:...
)
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 2.1 Build the migration project because they are not in the official dependencies of the web application
call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_PATH%" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Code\mig.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 3. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)
```

2.1 is the step I added to compile the mig.csproj, however, I (have not tested it yet) assume that 3 will not work as intended because it would miss the dlls I generated in the 2.1 step.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, separating the models from the migration makes sense. But you should also **separate the deployments.** In you case I would have two builds (1 for the web app, 1 for the migration) which will push two (build) artefacts to a drop location. Then I would have two release definitions where the first will run the fluent migrator assembly against your sql connection string to update the db. And the second will update the web app.

I like to use [Visual Studio Team Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/services/visual-studio-team-services/) (VSTS) for that scenarios.

Comment: yet, assuming I cannot use VSTS, I can only do thru kudu, how would you do it?

Comment: I would probably run the migration from my local pc and don't push any migration assembly to the web app. But that is not my preferrd solution.